# remote methode invocation for c

Tags: java, c, rmi, middleware

Is there any equivalent middleware for c like rmi for java or .net for c#?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is the standard library but I doubt that's the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There's the original [ONC RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONC_RPC) much loathed by myself in my younger days.  There's [DCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model).  There's [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA).  There are also C implementations for SOAP and probably many of the other varieties of [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Answer (score 1):

Look up CORBA, a standard for middleware that can work with C.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom protocols, or use SOAP (WebServices).

I would suggest you using WebServices with Apache's [AXIS](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to communicate between a Java application and .Net application or write and a service layer and application in .Net using C#?

In either case you would probably want to use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx). If you want to communicate between a Java and .Net application you will want to look at [Sun's Project Tango](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/glassfish/ProjectTango/).

[Consuming WCF service in Java](http://dotnetclr.blogspot.com/2009/08/consuming-wcf-service-in-java.html)

Comment: Reading the title and description again I am not really sure what language you are after. Could you clarify what you want as this doesn't make sense: ".net for c#"

Comment: i intended to code in c. since the rmi stuff for java is quite easy to implement i'll use java.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RPCGEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN) , that generates C code (client and server) to do remote call and shoulb installed by default on a unix computer. That's really easy to use , and you could find plenty of tutorial on the net.
That might be outdated, but I have only try Corba and Soap with C++, so I don't how they fit with plain C.

Answer (score 0):

For use with C and C++ there is gSOAP an open source SOAP framework.